# Flutter version solving failed (could not find package)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, dart-null-safety

I just clone a GitHub project, but it does not working, it gives me some version issues I think, but I don not get what the actual problem is? Please anyone do help me. this is the error I got while running the project and pub get.

```
C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat --no-color pub get Running "flutter pub get" in multiple_image_selector... 2,603ms Running "flutter pub get" in example... Because example depends on multi_image_selector from path which doesn't exist (could not find package
multi_image_selector at "..\..\multi_image_selector"), version solving failed. pub get failed (66; Because example depends on multi_image_selector from path which doesn't exist (could not find package multi_image_selector at "..\..\multi_image_selector"),
version solving failed.) Process finished with exit code 66
```

This is the pubspec.yml file

```html
name: multi_image_selector description: A new Flutter package. version: 0.0.1 author: HuanSuh
<huansuh@gmail.com>
  homepage: "https://github.com/flutterstudygn/multiple_image_selector" environment: sdk: ">=2.2.2
  <3.0.0 "

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  multi_image_picker: ^4.6.1
  image_cropper: ^1.2.0
  photofilters: ^1.0.5
  carousel_slider: ^1.4.1
  path: ^1.6.4
  path_provider: ^1.5.1
  provider: ^3.1.0+1

  firebase_storage: ^3.1.1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # To add assets to your package, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #  - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #  - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg
  #
  # For details regarding assets in packages, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages
  #
  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants ", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # To add custom fonts to your package, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter " section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family " key with the font family name, and a "fonts " key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts in packages, see
  # https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

Comment: How did you cloned the project? Did you get all of it, or just example folder inside that repo?

Comment: yes, all of it, not just example folder.